# Why is there an X under target when I try to run my app on a device?

Tags: android, eclipse, target

I am running eclipse on windows, and trying to put a slightly updated version of a program on a phone, however there is an X under the target of the device looking like "X 2.3.5". I reset the program to before I made any updates and it still will not work right, even though I used an old version of the exact same program this morning, is there an update I missed or something I need to update? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `android:minSdkVersion=` declared in the `AndroidManifest` is not greater than the phone SDK's version.

In a such scenario the application detects that the sdk version of the phone is lower than the required miminum sdk version of the application, and prevent it from being installed.

Comment: Here is the thing, it installed fine, but parts of the program are not working. I have not touched this program in about a month, and it was working back then, I made no changes to it, and now it is not working for whatever reason.

Comment: Could you double check and tell us what is the `minimumSdkVersion` declared in the `AndroidManifest`, and the version of your phone from `Settings -> About Phone: Android Version`.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
Android Version is 2.3.5

Comment: Hm.... Just for testing purposes try to set a lower min SDK version, for example = 8.

Comment: On a whim i tried running the app on an emulator and it looks like somehow my problem is not the sdk, but an unparsable date that I can not find lol. I suppose I will put up a new post to try find that, thanks for all your help!